# Geocoding API: Daily quota 2500 exceeded

Tags: google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I'm facing an issue with Geocoding API. My website has exceeded the daily quota (2.500) and the search engine stopped working.

I would like to know how to increase this quota as soon as possible because of the production environment is being impacted due to this.

Is there a workaround to solve that?

The website is:

[www.pizzariaweb.com.br](http://www.pizzariaweb.com.br)

This is a sample of the result page:

http://pizzariaweb.com.br/pizzarias/03335-080/pizzaria-em-jardim-analia-franco-sao-paulo-sp-rua-alonso-calhamares.html

Comment: Voting to close because it's about third party services, not about programming

Comment: Are you sure you can't geocode on the client side, saving you all this hassle?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about usage of a third party service instead of directly about programming.

Comment: Have you read the Usage Limit Section on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro ? It mentions the 2500 requests and the Google Maps API for Work if you need more. Also look at the note about client side geocoding.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to enter your credit card for identification verification.

From google : - 
 Verify your identity to get up to 150 000 requests per 24 hour period, by enabling billing on the Google Developers Console. A credit card is required for verification. We ask for your credit card purely to validate your identity. Your card will not be charged for use of the Google Places API Web Service.

https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/usage

Hope i help.